# How to tell Xcode that a .h is a counterpart of a .m? (messed up after Refactor->Rename)

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode 4.2, and I used Refactor->Rename on a class I created, which also renamed the file names.

After the refactor, Xcode could no longer recognize that these 2 files are counterparts - this means the assistant editor wouldn't display the counterpart, and the keyboard shortcut to switch to counterpart wouldn't work.

Is there any way to tell Xcode that these files are actually counterparts?

Comment: I believe this is temporary due to indexing problem. When in `.m` file press Cmd+Shift+J (which is "Show in Navigator" equivalent). Afterwards that, the shortcuts for switching between interface/implementation should work as well as assistant editor.

Comment: sounds good, but I already solved it and can't reproduce to check if it's ok. I'm not sure it was temporary though... the .h file was highlighted as red...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out removing the reference for the renamed files and re-adding them does the trick.

I'm wondering if there was another way though - and why it happened in the first place (doesn't always reproduce)...

Answer (score 1):

**Restarting XCode** worked for me :)